# Mover scroll de <iframe>, <embed> ou <object> com PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um projeto de leitura online, estou utilizando a tag `iframe` para exibir o `pdf` na pagina. Preciso salvar a posição do `scroll` e restaurar na proxima leitura. Trecho de exemplo:

```
 <html>
    <head>
       <script src='jquery.js'></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <iframe src='documento.pdf' width='800px' heigth='600px'>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Poderia utilizar a tag embed ou a tag object, ao invés de iframe, é a mesma coisa??

Comment: Duas perguntas: o PDF/iFrame está no mesmo dominio? queres guardar isso onde? (servidor, cookie, ou outra maneira)

Comment: Sim o documento está no mesmo dominio. Vou guardar no servidor.

Comment: Com plugin do Adobe Reader, talvez seja melhor o jsPDF

Comment: Mas o jsPDF não é para gerar PDF? Eu já tenho os ebooks, quero apenas mover o scroll do iframe com pdf, mas descobri que dessa forma não será possivel, vou tentar outra solução.